# What is the best function to get Date, compare Date, get hour I should use in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

i create online store which had products, i want the system to get the time and date when the user post their products, and store the time to database, and also i want to display the products according their input time.

so my question is : what is the best function to get date, compare date, get hour i should use in php?

i got some suggestion from internet that i should use time() to get second and convert it

this is simple code to handle those

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            function secondToYear($sec){
                $year = $sec * 0.0000000316887646;
                return $year;
            }

            function secondToMonth($sec){
                $month = $sec * 0.000000380265176;
                return $month;
            }

            function secondToDay($sec){
                $day = $sec * 0.0000115740741;
                return $day;
            }

            $second = time();
            echo "second : ".$second;//in second
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            echo "year : ".  secondToYear($second);
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            echo "month : ".  secondToMonth($second);
            ?>
            <br>
            <?php
            echo "days : ". secondToDay($second);
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

i got the formula from google, but when i compare the result with the result from [this](http://www.unit-conversion.info/time.html) it didnt match

Comment: Almost all DB's have a built in method to do this, something like a datefield with the value `NOW` etc.

Comment: You shouldn't depend on the client for dates or times, the system could be set to anything.

Comment: This is neither a javascript or css question. Don't tag questions with something they are not

Comment: @adeneo could you please give me the link related with your post? thanks^^

Comment: The stone age called, they want their formulas back!

Comment: @RobG is time() method asking current time from client not from server?

Comment: You've heard of [`date()`](http://php.net/date) before, right?

Comment: Avoid floating point numbers if you need precision as they are not that reliable with so many digits. `seconds / (3600*24*30)` will get you closer to the number you are looking for for a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic:**

```
// Current time
echo date("Y-m-d", time());

// 2013-12-01
echo date("Y-m-d", 1385925192);
```

--

**Output Date In Format**
The DateTime object has a date value, you can output this value by using the format() method and assigning what format to return in.

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Output Timestamp**
If you want to output the DateTime value as a timestamp you will use the method getTimestamp().

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

**Changing The Date**
To change the date on the object you will use the setDate() method.

```
$date = new DateTime();

// Outputs 2001-02-03
$date->setDate(2001, 2, 3);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Compare Two Dates**

```
$date1 = new DateTime('May 13th, 1986');
$date2 = new DateTime('October 28th, 1989');

$difference = $date1->diff($date2);
```

**Check this :**
http://www.paulund.co.uk/datetime-php

**And php.net Manual :**
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its companions ([`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)). They are all one needs for 95% of their processing of dates and times.

From the list of traditional PHP [date & time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php), take a look at [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (it parses English representations of time and produces timestamp values), [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) (if you need to express the date in other language than English; it works together with [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)) and [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) (if you need the current timestamp for whatever numerical purpose like using it as a pseudo-random number). Most of the other functions are either not needed in a usual PHP application or their functionality is provided by the `DateTime` class and their friends.